# does copy the source code after inject or vice versa in gulp with bower?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, bower

running angular js app on **ubuntu 14.04** with help of gulp. My folder structure is this

```
|-- app <--- main application folder
|-- bower_components
|-- bower.json
|-- env <--public folder; copy the main `/app` code while runtime  
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- node_modules
`-- package.json
```

Below are the task. see complete [gulpfile.js](http://pastebin.com/m7a5tegq)

I have added below in */app/index.html*

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

- `inject` : inject all bower_components JS into *env/index.html*

  ```
  gulp.task('inject', function () {
    var target = gulp.src('./app/index.html');
    var sources = gulp.src('./app/**/*.js');
    return target
      .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(), {read: false}),{       
         name: 'bower',
         relative:true}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(src))
  });
  ```

now **here is the issue**

Now if I write dest i.e. `.pipe(gulp.dest('./env'))` in above task , than nothing being added to *index.html* ( on both **/app** and **/env**  folder) .

and

If I write src i.e. `.pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))` than all bower_components js files being added into both *index.html* ( which I think, because of `copy` task which runs after `inject` )

```
      <!-- bower:js -->
      <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
      <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
      <script src="../bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
      <script src="../bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
      <script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
      <!-- endinject -->
```

- `copy` : which first complete browserify task and than copy all /app .html and .css to /env **This seems confusing !!**

  ```
  gulp.task('copy', ['browserify'], function() {
      gulp.src(['app/**/*.html','./app/**/*.css'])
          .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
          .pipe(browserSync.stream());
  });
  ```

  Now when we run `gulp` ; Firefox opens up but the files inside `<!-- bower:js -->` are added in page but browser can not find sources of these files. Kindly guide me

Do I need to use wiredep or useref  gulp modules or am I missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by the

- ordering of task( `copy` before `inject`)
- and changing in `browser-sync`

---

```
gulp.task('inject', ['lint', 'copy'] , function () {
      var target = gulp.src('./app/index.html');
      var minify_js = gulp.src('./app/**/*.js')
                        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
                        .pipe($.plumber())
                        .pipe($.uglify({ mangle: false, compress:true, output: { beautify: false } }).on('error', onError))
                        .pipe($.plumber.stop())
                        .pipe($.concat('vendor.js'))
                        .pipe($.rename({suffix: '.min'}))
                        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
                        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
      return target
            .pipe($.inject(
                gulp.src(mainBowerFiles(),{read: false}), {name: 'bower', relative: true}))
            .pipe($.inject(minify_js,{relative: true}))
            .pipe($.inject(
                 gulp.src('bower_components/**/*.css', {read: false}), {relative: true}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
    });
```

and

```
   gulp.task('browser-sync', ['inject'], function() {
        browserSync.init({
            server: {
                baseDir: './env',
                routes: {
                        "/env" : "env",
                        "/bower_components" : "bower_components"
                }
            },
            browser: ["chromium-browser"]
        });
    });
```

here is complete [gulpfile](http://pastebin.com/05aiE2zD), hope it helps someone. Thanks